# Equivalence proof by using identities and ‘n series of substitutions: (P ⋁ Q) → (P ⋀ Q) ≡ (P → Q) ⋀ (Q → P).

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

If any one can help me with this problem i would be grateful, since i have no past experience with propositional calculus . I tried using the following laws:

$¬ (¬ P) \equiv P\\
(P ∨ Q) \equiv (¬ P → Q)$

Contrapositive law: $(P → Q) \equiv (¬ Q→¬P)$

De Morgan’s law: $¬ (P ∨ Q) \equiv (¬ P ∧ ¬ Q) \text{ and } ¬ (P ∧ Q) \equiv (¬ P ∨¬ Q)$

Commutative laws: $(P ∧ Q) \equiv (Q ∧ P) \text{ and } (P ∨ Q) ≡ (Q ∨ P)$

Associative law: $((P ∧ Q) ∧ R) \equiv (P ∧ (Q ∧ R))$

Associative law: $((P ∨ Q) ∨ R) \equiv (P ∨ (Q ∨ R))$

Distributive law: $P ∨ (Q ∧ R) \equiv (P ∨ Q) ∧ (P ∨ R)$

Distributive law: $P ∧ (Q ∨ R) \equiv (P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ R)$

Comment: And write the problem to be answered in the text of the question.

Comment: The first step is to remove the $\to$ signs using *Material implication* : $(P ∨ Q) ≡ (¬ P → Q)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

Since almost all your laws involve $\land$'s, $\lor$'s and $\neg$'s, but few involve $\rightarrow$, it makes sense to rewrite any $\rightarrow$ in terms of $\lor$'s and $\neg$'s, so that then you can just focus on the $\land$'s, $\lor$'s and $\neg$'s.

So, for example, you can take $P \rightarrow Q$ and say:

$$P \rightarrow Q \equiv \neg \neg P \rightarrow Q \equiv \neg P \lor Q$$

Notice that in the first step I used $P \equiv \neg \neg P$, but I only applied that to the *component* statement $P$, rather than the whole statement $P \rightarrow Q$ ... and that's perfectly ok!  If you're new to this, that is something you may not have yet realized (in fact, maybe that's why you go stuck!).